# How can I call and display a Fragment inside a Fragment when an item from the RecycleView is clicked?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using Fragments (fragment_inventory.xml) and inside that are 2 Fragments as you can see the picture below. The left part is the Fragment with a RecycleView.

What I want to do is that when I click an option from the RecycleView from the options, let's say **Categories** is that a CategoryFragment will display on the right side of the Fragment.

I have this following code working from the past with ListView (Please see snippet below). But when I add it to my InventoryRecyclerViewAdapter.java (from the *I want to insert code here* spacing) is the `getFragmentManager()` will turn red.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

switch (position){
    case 0:
        ProductsFragment productsFragment = new ProductsFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.inventorylist_fragmentcontainer, productsFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        break;
```

Can you please advise me on what to do with this? Also, I want the selected RecycleView to be highlighted when clicked. Thanks

[image]
InventoryRecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class InventoryRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InventoryRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";
    private ArrayList<Integer> mIcon = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mLabel = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public InventoryRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> mIcon, ArrayList<String> mLabel) {
        this.mIcon = mIcon;
        this.mLabel = mLabel;
        this.context = context;
    }

    //responsible for inflating the view
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.customlayout_inventorylist, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull InventoryRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

            Glide.with(context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(mIcon.get(i))
                    .into(viewHolder.icon);

            viewHolder.label.setText(mLabel.get(i));

            viewHolder.customLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

----------------------------------------
     I want to insert a code here
----------------------------------------
            });

        }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mLabel.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        ImageView icon;
        TextView label;
        LinearLayout customLayout;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inventorylist_icon);
            label = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inventorylist_title);
            customLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inventoryoptions_layout);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }

    public interface onInventoryListener{
        void onInventoryClick(int position);
    }
```

InventoryListFragment.java

```
public class InventoryListFragment extends Fragment implements InventoryRecyclerViewAdapter.onInventoryListener{

    private static final String TAG = "InventoryListFragment";
    //variables
    private ArrayList<Integer> mIcon = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mLabel = new ArrayList<>();

    public InventoryListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inventory_list, container, false);


        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: started");
        initImageBitmaps(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void initImageBitmaps(View view){
        Log.d(TAG, "initImageBitmaps: preparing bitmaps");

        mIcon.add(R.drawable.ic_product);
        mLabel.add("Products");

        mIcon.add(R.drawable.ic_customer);
        mLabel.add("Services");

        mIcon.add(R.drawable.ic_category);
        mLabel.add("Categories");

        mIcon.add(R.drawable.ic_tag);
        mLabel.add("Discounts");

        initRecyclerView(view);

    }

    private void initRecyclerView(View view){
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.inventorylist_recycleview);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(getActivity())
                .build()); //adding a divider into the recyclerview list

        InventoryRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new InventoryRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), mIcon, mLabel);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    }

    //method created from OnInventoryListener from InventoryListFragment.java
    //handles the onclick for the recycleview items
    @Override
    public void onInventoryClick(int position) {

}
```

fragmentinventory.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.InventoryFragment"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/inventory_content">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/inventorylist_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.devcash.Fragments.InventoryListFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_inventory_list">

    </fragment>

    <View
        style="@style/Divider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/inventorylist_fragmentcontainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try `getActivity().getFragmentManager();`

Comment: Doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an interface with a method which will be passed in the constructor of the adapter.

```java
interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onClick(SomeData data);
}
```

In constructor for recyclerView, make add a reference to this

```java
public InventoryRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> mIcon, ArrayList<String> mLabel, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.mIcon = mIcon;
    this.mLabel = mLabel;
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

In viewHolder, set an onClickListener (the one with android.* as package)

```java
viewHolder.customLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onClick(/* PASS YOUR DATA HERE */);
});
```

Now when making an adapter in your activity or fragment, implement the listener and override the onClick(SomeData data) method. Now, from there you call call the fragment manager and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved this problem.

Instead of this

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
```

I just did this

```
`FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)v.getContext()).getSupportFragmenteManager(`);
```